# Any better algorithm possible here?

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to solve [this](http://www.codechef.com/SEP12/problems/CKISSHUG) problem in Python. Noting that only the first kiss requires the alternation, any kiss that is not a part of the chain due to the first kiss can very well have a hug on the 2nd next person, this is the code I have come up with. This is just a simple mathematical calculation, no looping, no iteration, nothing. But still I am getting a timed-out message. Any means to optimize it?

```
import psyco
psyco.full()
testcase = int(raw_input())
for i in xrange(0,testcase):
    n = int(raw_input())
    if n%2:
        m = n/2;
        ans = 2 + 4*(2**m-1);
        ans = ans%1000000007;
        print ans
    else:
        m = n/2 - 1
        ans = 2 + 2**(n/2) + 4*(2**m-1);
        ans = ans%1000000007
        print ans
```

Comment: The question is not that clear. Can you say what the answer should be for the first few n (up to say 6) so that the intended result is clear. Does your code give the correct answer for the small values of n?

Comment: For n = 4, answer will be 10, 5 => 14, 6 => 22. For 1,3, answers are already given. If you need further clarification, please let me know. Yes, it does give correct results. And I have checked with some other answers in the comments below in that page, they match with mine.

Comment: In Python you do not need semicolons to terminate statements.

Comment: Yeah yeah I know (see I didn't use it in other lines!), it was just by way of my habit from Perl...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this is a pretty simple recursion. `F(1) = 2` and for `F(n)` we have two choices:

- `n = H`, then the number of ways to kiss the remaining guests is simply `F(n-1)`
- `n = K`, then the number of ways to kiss the remaining guests is `2 ** k` where `k` is the number of remaining guests that the princess is not forced to kiss. Since she has to kiss every second remaining guest, `k = ceil((n - 1) / 2)`

Putting them together, we get `F(n) = F(n - 1) + 2 ** ceil((n - 1) / 2)`

My attempt, including taking everything mod 1000000007:

```
from math import ceil

def F(n):
    m = 1000000007
    a = 2
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        a = (a + pow(2, int(ceil((i - 1.0) / 2)), m)) % m
    return a
```

**EDIT:** Updated (much faster and more unreadable! `F(1e9)` takes about 3 minutes):

```
def F(n):
    m = 1000000007
    a = 2
    z = 1

    for i in xrange(2, n, 2):
        z = (z * 2) % m
        a = (a + z + z) % m

    if (n & 1 == 0):
        z = (z * 2) % m
        a = (a + z) % m

    return a
```

**EDIT 2:** After further thought, I realised the above is actually just:

```
F(n) = (1 + 1) + (2 + 2) + (4 + 4) + ... + (2 ** n/2 + 2 ** n/2)
     = 2 * (1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2 ** n/2)
     = 2 * (2 ** (n/2 + 1) - 1)
     = 2 ** (n/2 + 2) - 2
```

But if `n` is even, the last `2 ** n/2` only occurs once, so we have:

```
def F(n):
    m = 1000000007
    z = pow(2, n/2, m)

    if (n % 2 == 0):
        return (z * 3 - 2) % m
    else:
        return (z * 4 - 2) % m
```

Which runs much faster! (Limited by the speed of `pow(x, y, z)`, which I think is `O(lg n)`?)

And just because, here is the one-liner:

```
def F(n):
    return (pow(2, n/2, 1000000007) * (3 + n % 2) - 2) % 1000000007
```

Results:

```
1   => 2
2   => 4
3   => 6
4   => 10
5   => 14
6   => 22
7   => 30
8   => 46
9   => 62
10  => 94
1e6 => 902893650
1e7 => 502879941
1e8 => 251151906
1e9 => 375000001
```

Comment: What is the answer for n = 43?

Comment: @Cupidvogel `8388606`. You could copy paste and type `F(43)` yourself?

Comment: Strange, I am having an answer of 10485758, even though for the numbers you posted, our answer match.

Comment: @Cupidvogel *shrug*. The comments on the question site give `F(30) = 98302`, which is what I get too. What do you get?

Comment: No no, I am getting the correct answer now. Looks like there was a typo. Anyways, your code has the same problem as mine, both are getting a runtime error, which happens when bad things like division by zero, or large memory consumption happen. Any solution?

Comment: @Cupidvogel For what input are you getting a runtime error using my code? I ran it for 1 to 1000 without any issues. Also what is the error message?

Comment: Ummm, I tried 1000000, and it hung my computer so badly that I had to restart it! Of course I don't know what Codechef is using, but since their limit is 10^9, they are surely using that as one case! Try it!

Comment: @Cupidvogel `F(1000000) => 902893650L` Took about 20 seconds.

Comment: Then I don't know, may be my system isn't sturdy enough. Did you try with 10^9?

Comment: @Cupidvogel I had to change `range` to `xrange` because I got a memory error on `range(1, 1000000001)`. It runs but it's waaaay to slow (I let it run to 30M, took 3 minutes). The reason is a lot of redundant calculations from calling `pow` every step instead of storing it as you go. I have updated my solution to do this and it is now much faster (~5seconds to 30M) but still takes about 3 minutes to do `F(1000000000)`.

Comment: What is the meaning of those shifting operators here?

Comment: @Cupidvogel The same as shifting operators in any other language. `x << 1` is equivalent to `x * 2`. I was originally doing `z = z << 2; a = (a + z) % m` in the `for` loop, but this is actually slower than `z = z << 1; a = (a + z + z) % m`. Search me as to why.

Comment: What is the point of replacing `x**2` by `x << `? Both gives the same result.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16155/discussion-between-cupidvogel-and-veredesmarald)

Comment: @Cupidvogel I was just trying stuff to make it run faster. There is probably no appreciable difference between `z << 1` and `z * 2`.

Comment: Why is your code running faster than mine? Your one iterates over an array, which can be pretty lengthy if the array length is huge. Whereas in mine, there is no iteration, only a one-time calculation.

Answer (score 11):

You're computing powers with very large exponents, which is extremely slow if the results are not reduced in process. For example, a naive computation of `10**10000000 % 11` requires creating a 10000000-digit number and taking modulo 11. A better way is [modular exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) where you reduce modulo 11 after each multiplication and the integer never gets larger.

Python provides built-in modular exponentiation. Use `pow(a,b,c)` to compute `(a**b) % c`.

This is under assumption that your algorithm is correct, which I did not verify.

Comment: How can I do modular exponentiation in these two lines of code: `ans = 2 + 2**(n/2) + 4*(2**m-1); ans = ans%1000000007;`?

Comment: Just replace `a**b` with `pow(a,b,1000000007)`, so `M = 1000000007; ans = (2 + pow(2,n/2,M) + 4*(pow(2,m,M)-1))%M`

Comment: But now it is showing wrong answer, so definitely some error in my algo. Can you spot it?